# SQL Server Agent job losing data inserting to MySQL via ODBC

Tags: mysql, sql-server

We have a large SQL Server database that uses agent jobs to insert records of outgoing messages into a MySQL table on another server that is a open queue. Problem is when we get to records that are more than 5000, it starts to lose records. So 7800 transferred, only 5500 will actually be inserted. But the job reports that it successfully ran.

The jobs run a dots file that defines the database connections via the servers ODBC. What's weird is we never had any issues before and I suspect its because of the earlier MySQL drivers. We had to use new ones because the old wouldn't install on the new server platforms.

Here is the error we're getting:

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  2:58:45 PM  Error: 2022-02-18 14:59:46.59     Code: 0xC002F210     Source: Transfer to MySQL Execute SQL Task     Description: Executing the query "INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(TABLE, 'SELECT sql_id..." failed with the following error: "Query timeout expired". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  2:58:45 PM  Finished: 2:59:46 PM  Elapsed:  60.778 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

If it ever fails it happens right at the 60sec mark.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen? Are there settings that need to be altered to ensure the transfer completes?

Please let me know what I can provide to assist.

Thank you all!!!

Comment: Guessing isn't likely to help. You will need to add instrumentation and start logging important information as it passes between the systems. No idea what "run a dots file" means. Using a table as a queue will require careful approach to locking, with a focus on avoiding race conditions. I suggest you ignore the command timeout error for now - "losing" rows seems to be far more important and proper error handling should correctly account for errors during export.

Comment: @Scott          This is a pretty solid clue - "Query timeout expired".  Please post your results from MySQL Command Prompt for SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%'; for analysis of your MySQL side of the world.  Other people may assist with analysis of the .NET side of the problem.

Comment: What's the default command timeout in your MySQL driver? Figure out the specific version of the driver you're using, because v5.7.4-v5.7.7 briefly used `max_statement_time` as a setting but newer versions use `max_execution_time`.

Comment: Hey All, thank you for the feedback. And yes i am currently waiting to hear back on what the max setting are for mysql. But of course out of 10 jobs that we use, the one that was causing all the problems (the dtsx package) is the only one that has the timeout set to 60 where all the others are 0. I hate and love when it is a simple over site. Hopefully this is it and wasting everyone's time. Thanks!!!